# How to show/hide text using a checkbox without js

Tags: html, css

I am trying that when I check the box with id "expand", the rest is shown, and normally while the box is unchecked, it is not shown, but I can't get it to show, any tips or ideas?

```css
div div p {
  display: none;
}

#expand:checked .checkbox {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <div>Pincha para recibir información:
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="expand" value="yes">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <p><input type="checkbox"> Tenerife</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox"> Tenerife</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox"> Tenerife</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox"> Tenerife</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox"> Tenerife</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox"> Tenerife</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox"> Tenerife</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide div when checkbox checked without JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45767754/hide-div-when-checkbox-checked-without-javascript)

Comment: the other answer solved my question, thanks anyway ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by using the sibling selector, `+`, and targeting the container div instead of the paragraph:

```css
div div.checkbox {
  display: none;
}

#expand:checked + .checkbox {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <div>Pincha para recibir información:
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="expand" value="yes">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <p><input type="checkbox"> Tenerife</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox"> Tenerife</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox"> Tenerife</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox"> Tenerife</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox"> Tenerife</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox"> Tenerife</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox"> Tenerife</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```