# Toggle div by checkbox (without JS)

Tags: css

I want to toggle a `<div>` via a checkbox.

```html
<div class="docs">...</div>

...

<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-docs">
```

The docs should only be visible if the checkbox is checked.

This should work without JS.

Up to now I only found solutions which require the checkbox to be near the div (via `+` or `~` selector).

Is there a way to solve this with modern CSS?

Answer (score 1):

This is doable with [:has](https://caniuse.com/css-has), which has baseline support since December 2023.

```css
div.docs {
    display: none;
}

body:has(#toggle-docs:checked) div.docs  {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="docs">...</div>

<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-docs">
```

This shows docs only if the checkbox is checked.

Answer (score -1):

using the adjacent sibling combinator (+) in CSS, even if the checkbox is not directly adjacent to the `<div>` you want to toggle. You can achieve this by using the `:checked` pseudo-class along with the adjacent sibling combinator.

```css
#toggle-docs:checked + .docs {
  display: block;
}

.docs {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-docs">
<div class="docs">...</div>
<label for="toggle-docs">Toggle Docs</label>
```

Comment: He would want to use the `~` subsequent-sibling selector, not the adjacent sibling selector. This does only work if the .docs div is adjacent to the checkbox. The subsequent-sibling selector will work for any sibling element with the same parent. However, the question itself states that they are not siblings and he cannot use either `+` or `~`